# What is difference between using $uri and $uri$args in try_files directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

For my other Angular apps, I am using the below config and everything seems to work fine.

```
location / {
     try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}
```

Now the one which I am working has nested folders within the dist folder.

And folder structure is something like:

```
dist \
  -- assets
  -- folder1
     -- folder2
        -- folder3
        -- folder4
        -- folder5
        index.html
  index.html
```

And the inner index.html is called with query params, and the url will be like - `<ip>/folder1/folder2/index.html?a=1&b=2&c=3`. But this is returning the fallback index.html at the root location. Later, I changed the above location block like this and it started working properly.

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

So I am not clear why the first location block didn't work. And I can't find anything in docs - [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: Btw. you shouldn't use `$uri$args`, since it allows local file inclusion, i.e. you can access all files on the server, e.g. `https://your-domain.com/?../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the parameters of a `try_files` statement **except the last parameter** are looking for filenames in the local file system.

So given the URI `/foo/bar`, the term `$uri$args` will search for a local file at `/path/to/root/foo/bar`, and if it does not exist will move on to the next term or the default clause at the end of the statement.

In the above case, `$args` is empty. However, given the URI `/foo/bar?baz`, the term `$uri$args` will search for a local file at `/path/to/root/foo/barbaz`.

I don't know why anyone would use `$uri$args` or `$uri$args/` as file terms on a `try_files` statement, but there may well be a legitimate use case.

The last parameter of a `try_files` statement is special. It can be a status code (for example `=404`), a named location to branch to, or a URI.

In the case of a URI, Nginx will **internally** redirect to that URI. A typical example might be `/index.php$isargs$args` - in this case it is perfectly legitimate to append the `$args` parameter, as we are creating a new URI and keeping the original argument string.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this => "In the above case, $args is empty. However, given the URI /foo/bar?baz, the term $uri$args will search for a local file at /path/to/root/foo/barbaz.", and didn't find this behavior in the docs.

Comment: After your explanation, I too am not sure of when $uri$args would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: A short answer to your question is never. It will do nothing good in any case.

Comment: Another thing is that $uri$args allows for path traversal as /?../../../../../../etc/passwd will give you a result in that case because args are not sanitized.